# How to write customizable function templates in modern C++?

Tags: templates, c++11

I have been writing function templates as
single function template that delegates to a class template according to
[Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)
with some small changes, like this:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lTBLZJGL5iDCWqci

It works good for me, but I would like to know if there are better ways in modern C++.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no real problem to solve. You may want to ask on CodeReview.

Comment: This would be off-topic on Code Review unless and until the code to be reviewed is included with the question.

Comment: @black, Phrancis:  I should have made more definite question. Thank you very much.